# Raycasting HTML elements with ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, raycasting

we are facing one problem with ThreeJS. We are trying to include HTML elements within ThreeJS and we are raycasting to get if we are pointing to any HTML element. But when we intersect it, returns an empty array. A simple example is the next one:

https://codepen.io/wazosa/pen/OJrqRRy?editors=1111

```
 mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(scene, true);
  console.log(intersects)
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    
        var object = intersects[0].object;


  }
```

You have a div and a cube, when you click over the cube it returns a console with it, but when you try to click on div element it returns an empty array. Any suggestions?

Thx in advance

Comment: Three.js' raycaster intersects objects in a Three.js scene. Your HTML element is just an HTML element you add to the DOM, it's not "within Three.js". How would the raycaster know this element? Try a normal Javascript event listener on the element instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Raycaster` works against objects that have a `raycast` method, like `Mesh`. When you call `raycaster.intersectObject( scene, true )`, the `Raycaster` recurses through `scene` looking for objects with the `raycast` method. When it finds one, it executes that method to determine if there are any intersections.

DIVs and other HTML elements are not part of the three.js scene. They are part of the webpage's DOM. `Raycaster` cannot intersect them because it doesn't even know they're there.

### Option 1

You could write the text to a texture and create a [`Sprite`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=sprite#api/en/objects/Sprite) to show the label. `Sprite` supports the `raycast` method.

### Option 2

You could add an analog to the scene represent the HTML element. This should probably be a transparent `Sprite` or some other kind of billboard to ensure the orientation remains correct. The trick will be ensuring the positioning matches the 2D positioning of the HTML element.

### Option 3

You could add a click handler (or similar event) to an element that contains labels. When you click, the event object should include a `target` property, which should be the HTML element you clicked on, regardless of the listener's host element. Other event properties include the 2D click position, although you will need to project that into 3D space if you're trying to get a 3D point.

Comment: nice answer, sadly  but thx :D !